# VSCode, Flutter SDK Version Erroneous?

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code, sdk, version

I believe my Flutter SDK version is being erroneously reported and do not know where the conflict is.

When running `flutter doctor` it reports `Flutter 2.2.3 • channel stable`. However, the bottom toolbar in VSCode displays `Flutter: 2.0.4`.

Is there a reason VSCode and terminal would report the Flutter version differently? And how can I ensure I am running the correct SDK version?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look into "dart.flutterSdkPath" setting in vscode and change if needed. The problem could be with you having multiple versions of Flutter on the disk and auto-find fails to find the correct one (last version), manually override.

Answer (score 1):

In my case my path( environment variables) of SDK was set wrong check yours first
and if still not worked try running commands
Flutter clean
Flutter upgrade